# Rails 3 route :except options are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

When i run "rake routes" the resultant list is so long that it takes a while for me to find what i need. I have used the exception clause successfully when the routes were plain vanilly, but in the case below, i have been unable to come up with the right construct to make it work.

```
  resources :answers, :except => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy] do
    collection do
      post :update_result
    end

    collection do
      post :calculate_and_save
    end
  end
```

The result of "rake routes" continues to produce the new, create, edit, update, show and destroy routes. Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your *full* ```config/routes.rb``` file? Edit: Also why don't you place those two ```post``` members in the same ```collection``` block?

Comment: @basicxman. LOL... that was the problem. I did as you suggested and that fixed the problem. If you post your comment as an answer, i'll check it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two `post` calls should be in the same `collection` block like so:

```
collection do
  post :update_result
  post :calculate_and_save
end
```

Comment: actually "post :update_result, :calculate_and_save" (all on the same line) is what i put in my routes file.

Comment: I'm not a giant fan of placing two non-standard actions on a single line but yes that will work.